# Query a table by one or multiple array values

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run a query to determine if a column A is true. If its true, get the contents of a different column B (possible array separated by ",") and use those contents to query a different table. My problem is, column B may be one number or may be 10 numbers all separated by "," and I need to query the second table for a column for each of the numbers of the previous query. If someone can help that would be great.

edit: I tried to use the array explode function but can't figure out how to query the next table to include those values.

I picture it being something like

```
query = select * from table where location = arrayValue[1] or location = arrayValue[2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adaptation of Telmo Marques here but improved :

```
<?php
//Let's say $bcolumn is a string with the values of B column, separated by colons
$bcolumnArray = explode(",", $bcolumn);
array_walk($bcolumnArray, 'htmlentities');

//Build SQL query
$SQL = 'SELECT * FROM table';
if(count($bcolumnArray)){
    $SQL.= ' WHERE IN ("'.implode('", "', $vbcolumnArray).'")';
}

//Query your second table here
$Qry = mysql_query($sql);

// Results here :
while($Res = mysql_fetch_assoc($Qry)){
    print_r($Res);
}
?>
```

I would suggest PDO also... take a look : [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Do I run a foreach() to display the results?

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's `explode()` function to transform your string into an array.

```
<?php
//Let's say $bcolumn is a string with the values of B column, separated by colons
$bcolumnArray = explode(",", $bcolumn);

//Build SQL query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ";
for($i=0; $i < count($bcolumnArray); $i++)
{
   $sql .= "location = " . $value;
   if($i != count($bcolumnArray)-1)
   {
      $sql .= " or ";
   }
}

//Query your second table here
mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Sorry, just edited my post. I need to query the "location" column for each of the return values.

Comment: @Rob I've edited my answer. Please note I didn't actually test this code for errors.

Comment: You're slamming `$value` into the SQL query and executing it blindly, which is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. **Do not do this**. Use [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) if you don't know how to escape things properly. It doesn't matter that these might only be numbers in this case as it's a dangerous pattern to repeat with other data. Those numbers might come in as HTTP parameters which you have zero control over.

Comment: @tadman good point, you're right. I didn't account for that to keep the example simple and more readable.

Comment: Simple and readable is great...until it ends up in production.

Comment: @tadman it's an *example* to describe an *approach*. You can't expect it to be the most secure and optimized code in the world. Introducing such things here would only confuse whomever is trying to learn something. This is not production code.

Comment: @tadman Telmo is right. It's not for production code, it's for learning. When you first started I am pretty sure you were doing code similar to that because we all did at our first language... When you understand the concept behind the approch, it's easy to redo it in a good way and secure.

Comment: If I could go at least *one* page in the MySQL tag without finding someone using dangerously unescaped SQL calls, I might agree with you. When you provide an answer without pointing out the inherent danger of the method employed, how is the developer to know? They'll cut and paste it, find it works, and push it to production. The way people learn today, from examples such as these, is entirely different from when I learned, which was almost exclusively from published books.